# How to use random function to get values from an interval

Tags: javascript

So basically i got this function

```
Math.random()
```

we were taught to use this formula in order to get values from 1 to x

```
parseInt(Math.random()*x)+1;
```

but now what i want to do is to get values from x to y but i'm not sure how to do it .. any help ?

Comment: `parseInt(Math.random()*y)+x`

Comment: @TheBombSquad that won't work

Comment: @SagarV how come? it seems to work on my end.. the only assumption is that `y > x`

Comment: @TheBombSquad for example, if you want to get a number between 12 and 25, the above code, `parseInt(Math.random()*25)+12` can generate upto 36.

`parseInt(0.99 * 25)+12`

Comment: ah.. you're right ;-; tnx it would be `parseInt(Math.random()*(y-x))+x` my bad

Answer (score 0):

```js
const doRandom = (min,max) => {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

console.log(doRandom(5,9));
```